# In Google App Engine Standard (Python) create named logs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

ISSUE: Not able to create named logs

CODE:

```
    from google.cloud import logging
    client = logging.Client()
    # client = logging.Client.from_service_account_json('credentials.json')
    logger1 = client.logger("my_new_log_1")
    logger1.log_text("hello logger 1") 
    logger2 = client.logger("my_new_log_2")
    logger2.log_text("hello logger 2")
```

ERROR: 'module' object has no attribute 'info'

This code needs to run on Google App Engine Standard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using Google Stackdriver Logging in App Engine Standard python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223678/error-using-google-stackdriver-logging-in-app-engine-standard-python)

Answer (score 0):

The provided usage example, on the "Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries" [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries), indicates a statement similar to the one below, prior to your "logger=" line:

The name of the log to write to
log_name = 'my-log'

Comment: George, I updated the question, I would like to write from functions to named logs, maybe one process would log to an error log, another to success log.

Comment: Is the answer provided by Robbe to question "Error using Google Stackdriver Logging in App Engine Standard python" correct, with the edit of the 27th of Nov.?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223678/error-using-google-stackdriver-logging-in-app-engine-standard-python